# Issue with NDSolve, Solving coupled differential equations, Error test failure at x = some value

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

```
yEQ[x_] := 
 45/(4*3.14^4) gChi/gs x^2 BesselK[2, x] /. {gChi -> 2, 
   gs -> 106.7, MP -> 2.44*10^18(*GeV*)}
A = (2 Sqrt[2 ]*3.14)/(3 Sqrt[5]) gs^(1/2) MP /. {gChi -> 2, 
    gs -> 106.7, MP -> 2.44*10^18(*GeV*)};
init := 0.01

 SolveBEQNN[mChi_, SigmaV_] = 
  NDSolve[{y'[x] == (-A mChi)/x^2 SigmaV*(y[x]^2 - (yEQ[x])^2), 
    y[init] == (yEQ[init])}, y, {x, init, 100000}, 
   InterpolationOrder -> All, MaxSteps -> 10000000, 
   MaxStepFraction -> 1/100000, AccuracyGoal -> \[Infinity]];


 PSPI = y[2*50000] /. SolveBEQNN[100, 1.7*10^-9.9]
```

The above code gives correct result, however when I change the magnitude of the variables e.g.

```
 PSPI = y[2*50000] /. SolveBEQNN[100, 1.7*10^-8]
 NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at x == 0.5118756600640246`; unable to continue.
 InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {100000} lies outside the range of data in the 
 interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
```

it is giving the following output with error messages.

```
Out: {-1.14979*10^15}
```

which is not correct. How to avoid this and find the correct solution.

Comment: Your code in any case gives the wrong result.

Comment: Can you specify the reason?

Comment: I just ran your code and got three messages: NDSolve::ndnum: `Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0.01.`

`NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at x == 0.03051719479497417`; unable to continue.`

`InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {100000} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.`

Comment: Please check with PSPI = y[2*50000] /. SolveBEQNN[100, 1.7*10^-11], It will provide results without showing the last two error message. First one is coming because I am using variables in NDSolve.

Comment: Do you want to check your code or solve a problem?

Comment: The problem is that this code works for certain values of SigmaV. Say for SigmaV=1.7*10^-11, the code works however for SigmaV=10^-9, it does not produce correct result. I want to know why this is happening and how the code can be corrected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely have opted for `ParametricNDSolve` for equations with unknown parameters; `NDSolve`, I use it for the equations which with deterministic variables. Also, Set delayed can often cause process to fail. Another change I made is using `StiffnessSwitching` method. This is what I did:

```
    yEQ[x_] =  45/(4*3.14^4) gChi/gs x^2 BesselK[2, x] /. {gChi -> 2, gs -> 106.7, MP -> 2.44*10^18(*GeV*)}
    A = (2 Sqrt[2]*3.14)/(3 Sqrt[5]) gs^(1/2) MP /. {gChi -> 2, gs -> 106.7, MP -> 2.44*10^18(*GeV*)};
    init = 0.01
```

Now

```
    SolveBEQNN = ParametricNDSolve[{y'[x] == (-A mChi)/x^2 SigmaV*(y[x]^2 - (yEQ[x])^2), 
                y[init] == (yEQ[init])}, y, {x, init, 100000}, {mChi, SigmaV},  Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
```

gives

```
   y[100, 1.7*10^-8][2*50000] /. SolveBEQNN
   (*7.18485*10^-12*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works.